# Cypress wildcard to broad in intercept

Tags: cypress

I want to intercept a `GET` request but it doesn't work as I wanted:

```
        // https://***.com/api/v1/receipt/suggestions?type=receipt&finance_type=purchase&is_invoice=0&cache_buster=FlYeNfBNG5ZY66
        // https://***.com/api/v1/receipt/630ba8b4f7005c058a702534?cache_buster=LcsJ1esqykcp93
```

```
        cy.intercept({
            method: 'GET',
            url: `${Cypress.env('API_URL')}/api/v1/receipt/*?cache_buster=*`,
        }).as('getReceipt');
```

This intercept intercepts the first url, but I want to intercept the second url. Any suggestions how to make the `*` more strict?

Comment: Have you tried using the `**` in the first part of the wildcard?

Comment: Are you sure it intercepts the first URL? It does not contain the `?cache_buster` part. The second URL does.

Comment: It does have that @MartinvanDriel :)

Comment: @PeterBoomsma It starts with `&`, not `?` in the first URL. Does your pattern require a question mark, as described in `*?cache_buster=*`? Or maybe that's part of the regex syntax.

Comment: The data of the intercept shows `"https://****.com/api/v1/receipt/suggestions?type=receipt&finance_type=purchase&is_invoice=0&cache_buster=KctS55LIMfg664"`